# Flutter vertical slider

Tags: flutter

I am making an app in flutter and I am curious how I can make a animnated kind of slider, to select a value.

Similar to this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnQGb.jpg
Is there a package for this?

I have something like a bar but not segmented like this

```dart
       Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "01",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 6,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.6,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                ),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    AnimatedContainer(
                                      height: _indicatorHeight,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                      ),
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "08",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) / [Widget of the Week video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufb4gIPDmEs)

```dart
double _currentSliderValue = 20;

return Slider(
      value: _currentSliderValue,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
      label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
          _currentSliderValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
```

The only problem left is the rotation, for this you can wrap the Slider inside a [RotatedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html)

```dart
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 3,
  child: YOURSLIVER
)
```

In the gif you provided it looks like as if your sliver should be over some other Widgets. To achive this you can use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) / [Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8)

or when displaying on top of the whole page you can use a invisible
[ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) / [Medium guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433)